# Problem between tcolorbox and shortvrb

Tags: tcolorbox

How to avoid the following problem: If I load `tcolorbox` then the white spaces are replaced by another character. I tried with `verb` and changing the delimiter but it's always the same result.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{shortvrb}

\AtBeginDocument{\MakeShortVerb{\|}}
\begin{document}
   
| Essai | strange !

\begin{tcolorbox}
|tcolorbox doesn't like spaces|
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: update the latex tools bundle, should fix it

Comment: update. That was a bug in the verbatim package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, the update was necessary! Thanks Ulrike and David